# A value of type 'Future<bool>' can't be returned from the function because it has a return type of 'Future<void>'

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I have:

```dart
Future<bool> foo() async => true;
```

This is allowed:

```dart
Future<void> bar()  {
  return foo(); // Works
}
```

but this is not:

```dart
Future<void> baz() async {
  return foo(); // Error
}
```

In both `bar` and `baz` I'm returning a `Future<bool>`, but why first works but second fails?

---

**Note:** This question isn't about **HOW** to make it work but rather **WHY** one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: A method with return type "Future" should always have the async keyword.

Comment: Both are working here...

Comment: @Raegtime No, it's the opposite.

Comment: you r right! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart has special rules for `void` returning functions: You are not allowed to return a value *because* it's declared as not returning any value, so actually trying to return a value is probably a mistake.

The same happens without `Future`:

```dart
void qux() {
  return true; // Error, can't return value from void function
}
```

gives the error

```
A value of type 'bool' can't be returned from the function 'qux' because it has a return type of 'void'.
```

You are allowed to have `return e;` statements, but only if the type of `e` is `void`, `Null` or `dynamic`. (And you shouldn't even do that, those are just allowed in order to make existing code work.)
(A `=> e` body is always allowed, because people like to use it as a shorthand for just `{ e; }`, mainly because the formatter keeps it on one line. I still recommend using `{ e; }` as body of a `void` function.)

Generalizing that to `async` functions with `void` future return types,
you are not allowed to return an *actual* value from `Future<void> ... async` function. So, the only things you are allowed to return are `void`, `dynamic`, `Null`, `Future<void>`, `Future<dynamic>`, and `Future<Null>`.
A `Future<bool>` is neither of those.

What you should write instead is:

```dart
Future<void> baz() async {
  await foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Future<bool> foo() async => true;
```

**First Case**

```
Future<void> bar()  {
  return foo(); // Works
}
```

For the code above, the return of `Future<void> bar()` can return `foo()`, because the `bar()` not return directly the value of foo(), so the `bar()` can deal with `foo()` without no problem.

**But, in the second case:**

```
Future<void> baz() async {
  return foo(); // Error
}
```

The code above is return directly the generic type of `foo()` because the function of `baz()` include `async` tag, so it will be trouble with the `baz()` as `Future<void>`, which is we know that `foo()` as `Future<bool>`

Answer (score 0):

As I have observed when I am running the same code

```
Future<bool> foo() async => true;

Future<void> bar() {
  return foo(); // Works
}

Future<void> baz() async {
  // return foo(); // Error
}

void main() {
  print("direct =====${foo()}");
  print("bar==========${bar()}");
  print("bazz========${baz()}");
}
```

The response is

```
direct =====Instance of '_Future<bool>'
bar==========Instance of '_Future<bool>'
bazz========Instance of '_Future<void>'
```

this signifies that when the async keyword is not present it takes the return type of the returning value.

But of the bazz function it gives a quick fix to make the function

```
Future<Future<bool>>
```

so when async is added the function return type is taken as the main type